# intersection of two sets where one in non Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $V \subset [0,1] $ be a non measurable set, then $\exists \ \epsilon$ with $
 0<\epsilon <1$ such that for any measurable set $E \subset [0,1] $ with $\mu(E)\geq \epsilon$ then $A = V \cap E$ is non-measurable?

I am assuming this proposition is telling us that there exists a non-measurable subset of $V$.

To show this, I was thinking of constructing a set $E$ as a countable union of open intervals, assuming $A$ is measurable but then $E \cap V = V$ which is not measurable!

I am assuming I need to find such $\epsilon$?

What would be the contradiction? if $V$ is a vitali set, then $\mu (V \cap E) = 0$

Comment: You are not being asked to construct an $E$, if you were to construct anything here, it would be $\epsilon$ as this is the existentially quantified piece. You must then show that any $E$ with measure greater than the $\epsilon$ you have constructed has the property. For some intuition, pick a Vitali set, in the Lebesgue measure, and then multiply it by $1/2$. The intersection of this set and $[1/2,1]$ is measurable, and so is $[1/2,1]$ so $\epsilon>1/2$.

Comment: Is this the Lebesgue or Borel measure?

Comment: @JackM Lebesgue

Comment: @Zackkenyon What would be the contradiction? if $V$ is a vitali set, then $\mu (V \cap E) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

What you are being asked to prove is that, if $V \subseteq [0, 1]$ is not measurable, then, for some $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$, for every $E \subseteq [0, 1]$ with $\mu(e) \ge \varepsilon$, $V \cap E$ is not measurable.

Assume the statement is false. Then there is a set $V \subseteq [0, 1]$ that is not measurable and is such that, for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$, taking  $\varepsilon = 1 - 1/n$, you can find a measurable $E_n \subseteq [0, 1]$ with $\mu(E_n) \ge 1 - 1/n$ and $V \cap E_n$ measurable. But then with $F = \bigcup_n E_n$, you have that $F$ and $V \cap F$ are measurable and that $\mu(F) = 1$. So, under the Lebesgue measure, $V \setminus F$ is measurable (with measure $0$) so that $V = (V \cap F) \cup (V \setminus F)$ is measurable, contradicting our assumption that $V$ is not measurable.

Comment: I can see why $\mu([0,1] \setminus F) = 0$ but not why is $V \setminus F$ measurable and with measure $0$?

Comment: is it because $V \cap \bigcap_n E_{n}^c$ and  $\mu(\bigcap_n E_{n}^c) = 0$

Comment: $V \setminus F$ is a subset of the measurable zero set $[0, 1] \setminus F$. Under the Lebesgue measure, any subset of a set of measure 0 is measurable (with measure 0).

Comment: Isn't what he is being asked to prove that *every* set with measure greater than $\epsilon$ has non-measurable intersection with $\mathcal{N}$?

Comment: @Zackkenyon: thanks for pointing out the error. I believe I have fixed it.  The first paragraph was an afterthought and I got it wrong.